# How to check already downloaded files and download only missing ones with pytube?

Tags: python, download, pytube

I want to download only missing files when downloading playlists using pytube. How I can do that?

There is a playlist function:

```
def download_playlist():
    #get url for download
    playlist = Playlist(get_link)
    playlsit_name = playlist.title
    #creating folder
    main_dir = user_path + "\\" + playlsit_name

    if os.path.exists(main_dir):
        print("Error: Playlist folder already exists")
    else:
        os.mkdir(main_dir,mode = 0o666)
        videos_num = len(playlist.video_urls)
    #download playlist
    n=0
    for url in playlist:
        YouTube(url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(main_dir)
        #counting
        for files in os.listdir(main_dir):
            if files.endswith('.mp4'):
                n=n+1
                print("Prenašanje...    " + str(n) + "/" + str(videos_num))        
        for file in os.listdir(main_dir):
            if re.search('mp4', file):
                mp4_path = os.path.join(main_dir,file)
                mp3_path = os.path.join(main_dir,os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'.mp3')
                new_file = AudioFileClip(mp4_path)
                new_file.write_audiofile(mp3_path)
                #remove mp4
                os.remove(mp4_path)
                #adding metadata
                if var1 == 1:
                    full_file_name = os.path.basename(mp3_path)
                    file_name = Path(full_file_name).stem
                    channel_name = YouTube(url).author
                    substring = " - Topic"
                    if substring in channel_name:
                        channel_name = channel_name.replace(" - Topic", "")
                    audioFile = eyed3.load(mp3_path)
                    audioFile.tag.artist = channel_name
                    audioFile.tag.title = file_name
                    audioFile.tag.save()
    print("Download complete!!!")
```

When program is checking for folder, I would like to ask user if they want to override or skip arleady downloaded files and download only missing files.

Answer (score 0):

By nature of pytube, you are not able to find out if you have downloaded a file without re-downloading it, due to the way pytube handles naming files, since some YouTube titles are incompatible with the way we name files, this "bug?" if we can call it that, also happens if you try the playlist.title on the creation of the folder (I am sure you are able to write a function to replicate the way the YouTube title will be once downloaded, but i am not in the mood to look through every OS' file naming rules). This download_playlist method solves your problem, but relies upon you downloading the video to get the name the file would have. This script should satisfy your needs, but without the adding of metadata, I'll gladly answer more questions if it is needed about the script.

```
import os
from pytube import Playlist


def download_playlist(URL, overide):
    playlist = Playlist(URL) 
    playlsit_name = playlist.title 
    main_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), playlsit_name) 
    
    if not os.path.isdir(main_dir): # Makes a download path if there isn't one
        os.makedirs(main_dir)
        print("download folder for playlist has been created!")
    elif os.path.isdir(main_dir):
        if  overide in ["y","Y","yes"]:
            downloadExistingVideos = True
        else:
            downloadExistingVideos = False

    videos_num = len(playlist.video_urls)
    n=0
    for video in playlist.videos:
        input = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(output_path=main_dir,)
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(input) 
        os.rename(os.path.join(main_dir,input),os.path.join(main_dir,"output.mp4"))
        if ext == ('.mp4'):
            n=n+1
            print("Prenašanje...    " + str(n) + "/" + str(videos_num))        
        try:
            os.rename(os.path.join(main_dir,"output.mp4"),os.path.join(main_dir,base+".mp3"))
        except:
            if downloadExistingVideos == True:
                os.remove(os.path.join(main_dir,base+".mp3"))
                os.rename(os.path.join(main_dir,"output.mp4"),os.path.join(main_dir,base+".mp3"))
                print("overwriten done!")
            elif downloadExistingVideos == False:
                os.remove(os.path.join(main_dir,"output.mp4"))
                print("overwrite skipped!")
    print("Download complete!!!")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    URL = input("input URL>")
    overide = input("Do you want overwrite existing files?>")
    download_playlist(URL,overide)
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But your code has some errors. Some files that are downloaded cannot be played and one error with `input` in line 14.

Comment: the line 14 error shall be gone now. Sadly I don't know why some of the files that are downloaded cannot be played, if you could add the link to the playlist I would like to check out if it is a youtube problem, pytube problem, or a code problem. I highly recommend splitting the code up in smaller functions, which would make it possible to check if the folder exists before you answer if you wont to overide it, I decided to keep it as close as possible to your original code so you can decide how you want to split it into small functions yourself.